# How to remove text flicker in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html, text, hover

I am creating a div, with some text inside it which fades in, when you hover your cursor on the div (through javascript and css). But when you select the text and drag the cursor out, the text flickers. The text flickers on some other cases too. Here's the html with the js in the head:

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainDiv').mouseover(function(){
        $('#mainText').css('opacity', '1');
        $('#mainText').css('transition','all 0.2s ease');
        $('#mainText').css('transition-delay','0.35s');
    });
    $('#mainDiv').mouseout(function(){
        $('#mainText').css('opacity', '0');
        $('#mainText').css('transition','none');
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "mainDiv">
<div id="mainText">This is the main text which is inside the Div</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#mainDiv{
width:5%;
height:125px;
background-color:#930;
transition:all 0.7s;
display:inline-block;
white-space:nowrap;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 50px #000;
float:left;
color:#FFF;
}
#mainDiv:hover{
width:30%;
alignment-adjust:central;
}
#mainText{
opacity:0;
font-family:"Myriad Pro Light";
font-size:25px;
padding-top:20px;
text-shadow:0.2em 0.2em 0.5em #000;
text-align:center;
}
```

I think that maybe the problem is that when I hover over the text then it gets out of the div and so the text also goes transparent, which would need some little tweaks in the code (which I can't figure out). But if there's a better code for executing this program then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) event is fired when the mouse hovers over the child text element. Instead you should use [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) which is not fire when child elements are hovered:

> The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event
>   bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse
>   pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.

Try it like this instead:

```
$('#mainDiv').mouseleave(function(){
...
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8FdNy/1/)